# Is there such thing as short range only garage door opener?

Tags: garage-door-opener

Is there such thing as short range only garage door opener/remote? My opener can open the garage from the 3rd floor when I live and it bugs me that the opener might be pressed accidentally and it opens the garage without my knowledge. It's becoming something I have to worry about.

A remote that works only if it's in front and facing of the garage? I am looking for a solution to this issue other than putting the remote in a secure place. I still worry if I am carrying the remote safely on my way upstairs.

Comment: You may be able to add a small fariday cage around part of the antenna to reduce the effective range and make it slightly directional a metal fine wire mesh that is grounded like metal window screen may just do what you want. I don't know of any short range models.